# Realm NSPredicate query not working with non-Latin scripts

Tags: ios, swift, realm, nspredicate

I am using Realm with NSPredicate to filter a class of objects, for example

```
Card(
    word: "Test",
    translation: "Test"
),
Card(
    word: "Тест",
    translation: "Test"
),
Card(
    word: "تست",
    translation: "Test"
)
```

I then try to filter these with `.filter(predicate: NSPredicate)`.

This returns the first card from above:

```
let word = "Test" // Sample value
let filtered = realm.objects(Card.self).filter("word ==[c] %@", word)
print(filtered.count) // 1
```

But when I replace `word` with a non-Latin script, it returns no objects

```
let word = "تست" // Sample value
let filtered = realm.objects(Card.self).filter("word ==[c] %@", word)
print(filtered.count) // 0
```

Would this be a problem with NSPredicate or Realm? Or did I just write the query wrong? (I tried it with `==` instead of `==[c]` and with different scripts and still had the same problem.)

Thanks!

Comment: I am fairly sure this is just a typo in the question, but just to make sure: you wrote `Card` with a capital c in your second example as well, right?

Comment: I tried building a reproduction case based on the code you provided, and wasn't able to reproduce your results (got the Arabic result). What version of Realm are you using, and can you file an issue on our GitHub (https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues) with more details? Also, note that Realm [only supports case-insensitive queries on Latin-alphabet text](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#current-limitations).

Comment: @DávidPásztor The lowercase c was a typo when I was writing the question - fixed that 

Comment: @AustinZ I just tried the query again, except this time I copied the string directly from Real Browser (this returned the correct result). For some reason, this added a space before the word. It didn't do this with any of the other cards.

Comment: Okay, cool! So is everything working now, or do you still need help with your question?

Comment: I just rewrote the cards, and everything is working fine now. So it was probably a problem with an earlier version of the app, and not with the filtering

Comment: Awesome! Good luck with your app, and thanks for using Realm!